# ngx-translate not working in ng-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngx-translate

The `ngx-translate`'s `translate` pipe does not work inside the `ng-bootstrap`'s [modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples).

```html
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">
    {{ 'MODAL.TITLE' | translate }}
  </h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">
    <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> {{ 'BUTTON.CLOSE' | translate }}
  </button>
</div>
```

[image: Sample screen]

Comment: Even their demo stopped working. https://embed.plnkr.co/01UjWY3TKfP6pgwXKuEa/

Comment: Maybe the API the filter makes use of is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

On the `ngx-translate` [Readme](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/README.md), it's written :

> **NB: if you're still on Angular <4.3, please use Http from @angular/http with http-loader@0.1.0.**

So what are the differences?

In Angular >= 4.3.x, instead of providing `Http` to the `TranslateModule`, you now need to provide `HttpClient`:

**app.module.ts :**

```
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http"; //<-- before import {HttpModule, Http} from "@angular/http";
...
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) { //<-- before Http
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, "i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        HttpClientModule, //<-- before HttpModule
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient] //<-- before Http
          }
        })
    ],
    ...
})
```

I forked and fixed the Angular Demo (4.3.6) : https://plnkr.co/edit/1VZdWdQvat3lxaXYVZs3?p=preview

Comment: The `ngx-translate` works perfectly outside the `ng-bootstrap`'s modal. Appreciate if you can create a Plunker having these two integrated. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: @RogerNg here it is, I just moved the code into the modal and all seems to be working : https://plnkr.co/edit/z5bB63YihlRPYmJ3Giqh?p=preview is your modal in nested modules ?

Comment: I'm using the second example "components as content" for ng-bootstrap modal.

Comment: I have a main module and an app module. There is no relationship between main module and app module. The component is under the main module. The `TranslateModule.forRoot()` is imported in app module.

Comment: @RogerNg I made a separate component `modal.component.ts`. In `app.component.ts`, it calls the `<modal-component>` and pass its content to the modal. Is that what you're looking for? Working plunker here : https://plnkr.co/edit/SCgp90BmSzXbRAML37fj?p=preview